# Grails , How to accessing current ?lang in domain class

Tags: grails

```
http://localhost:8080/app/?lang=EN
-----------------------------------------------
```

---

### Domain

```
class Company {

  String nameJp

  String nameEn

  static constraints = {
  }

  String toString(){
    if(lang=='EN')
      return nameEn ? nameEn:nameJp
    else
      return nameJp
  }

}
```

How can i check current languages in domain class

Answer (score 2):

You can try `LocaleContextHolder` or pass the current Locale as param:

```
String toString() {
  return toString(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
}
//get the possibility of passing a Locale (better also for tests)
String toString(Locale locale) {

  if(locale.language == 'en') {
      return nameEn ? nameEn:nameJp
  } else {
      return nameJp
  }
}
```

But this is more a presentation need than a Domain Class need, so you can create a TagLib and handle this there.

```
class CompanyTagLib {

  static namespace = "comp"

  def name = { attrs ->
    Locale locale = attrs.locale ? attrs.remove('locale') : ResquestContextUtil.getLocale(request)
    Company company = attrs.remove('company')
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can access it in domain class, but in controller you can get it from session

```
session[SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME]
```

Comment: it's no such property session for domain class

Comment: when you accessing url http://localhost:8080/app/?lang=EN it assume request to server and request to server assume session. Use session from please (in .gsp, or in cntroller ) you are calling toString() Method